# Is it possible to change the font size of comments only in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

is there any way to change the font size only for comments in vs code? I can only change the ***`color`*** and ***`fontStyle`*** using the following code but ***`fontSize`*** doesnot work here. Is there any other way to acheive that?

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
            "comments": "#78aa7e",
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "comment",
                    "settings": {
                        "fontStyle": "italic", 
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```